# Cast from 32-bit address to 64-bit integer yields unexpected results

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion

Given the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    void* p = &i;

    printf("No cast, using %%p: %p\n",
        p);
    printf("Cast to unsigned long using conversion %%lx: %lx\n",
        (unsigned long) p);
    printf("Cast to unsigned long long using conversion %%llx: %llx\n",
        (unsigned long long) p);
    printf("Cast to unsigned long then unsigned long long using conversion %%llx: %llx\n",
        (unsigned long long) (unsigned long) p);

    return 0;
}
```

What would one expect the output to be? Compiling with GCC 4.4.7 and running the program given the following output:

```
No cast, using %p: 0xbf8aa3d8
Cast to unsigned long using conversion %lx: bf8aa3d8
Cast to unsigned long long using conversion %llx: ffffffffbf8aa3d8
Cast to unsigned long then unsigned long long using conversion %llx: bf8aa3d8
```

Compiling with clang version 3.4 and running the program yields what I would actually expect:

```
No cast, using %p: 0xbfa64234
Cast to unsigned long using conversion %lx: bfa64234
Cast to unsigned long long using conversion %llx: bfa64234
Cast to unsigned long then unsigned long long using conversion %llx: bfa64234
```

It would appear that GCC has padded the most significant bits with 1's instead of 0's when converting directly from pointer to unsigned long long. Is this a bug in GCC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7678099/47453

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is implementation defined as per the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.3.2.3` *Pointers* which says:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

`gcc` documents there implementation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation):

> The result of converting a pointer to an integer or vice versa (C90
>   6.3.4, C99 and C11 6.3.2.3).
>
> - A cast from pointer to integer discards most-significant bits if the pointer representation is larger than the
>     integer type, sign-extends1 if the pointer representation is smaller
>     than the integer type, otherwise the bits are unchanged.
> - A cast from integer to pointer discards most-significant bits if the
>     pointer representation is smaller than the integer type, extends
>     according to the signedness of the integer type if the pointer
>     representation is larger than the integer type, otherwise the bits are
>     unchanged.

Alternatively you could use *uinitptr_t* assuming `stdint.h` is available which is an unsigned integer that can hold a pointer value:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uintptr_t ip = &i ;

printf("0x%016" PRIxPTR "\n", ip ) ;
```